# SQL Server Merge query - duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have 2 table variables

- First table has `1, 3, 5`
- Second table has `2, 4, 5`

However when I run the following query :

```
 DECLARE @t1 TABLE (a int)
 DECLARE @t2 TABLE (b int)

 INSERT INTO @t1 (a) VALUES ( 1 ),(3),(5)  
 INSERT INTO @t2 (b) VALUES ( 2 ),(4),(5)

;WITH Source AS (
    SELECT * from  @t1
 )
 MERGE INTO @t2
 USING Source ON 1 = 0

 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (b) VALUES  (a);

 SELECT * FROM @t2
```

I get non-fully merged results :

Instead of getting `2, 4, 5, 1, 3`, I get `2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5`

**Question**

Why do I see a double `5` ? It is a merge query and 5 is matched to the other 5 in the second table.

Comment: `1 = 0`? That's always false. You don't need the CTE either, you can write `USING @t2 as source`, eg: `MERGE INTO @t2 using @t1 as source on a=b ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `on` clause is `1 = 0` nothing matches, so all rows are inserted.

Changing your `on` clause to `a = b` will yield your expected results of `2,4,5,1,3`.

rextester for `on a = b`: http://rextester.com/OPLL86727

It might be helpful to be more explicit with aliasing your source and target:

```
declare @t1 table (a int)
declare @t2 table (b int)
insert into @t1 (a) values ( 1 ),(3),(5)  
insert into @t2 (b) values ( 2 ),(4),(5)

;with source as (
  select * from  @t1
)
  merge into @t2 as target
  using source
    on source.a = target.b
    when not matched then
      insert (b) values  (a);

select * 
from @t2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are matching on 1=0 which will always fire the insert.  You should use On Source.a = @t2.b